# CSS Alignment in a menu

Tags: css, alignment

I've put an image in a superfish menu to separate list items. It seems to be jacking up the alignment on the menu. Any clue as to why and how to fix?

My code is super simple

```
    #menu .sf-menu li:not(:first-child):before {
    content: url('../images/menubord.png');
}
```

You can see it here:

[Menu](http://cafelafayettedinnertrain.com/wp)

Thanks for any assistance!

S

Answer (score 1):

You can position the image in relation to the list item:

```
#menu .sf-menu li:not(:first-child):before {
    content: url('../images/menubord.png');
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to make it with position, then use following it will work

```
#menu .sf-menu li:not(:first-child):before {
    content: url(../images/menubord.png);
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```